# Unable to clear gettext cache

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, gettext

I was playing around with the `gettext` hook in WordPress and did something like this:

```
add_filter("gettext", "test", 20, 3 );
function test($translation, $text, $domain) {
    return "hello world";
}
```

As expected, many of the menu items in the WordPress dashboard changed to "hello world". Now I can't change them back. Here's what I've tried:

1. Removing the code block above from `functions.php`
2. Restarting `php-fpm`
3. Restarting `nginx`
4. Restarting the server
5. Clearing WordPress cache (WP Super Cache)

I'm not really sure what else to try. Some menu items are still showing up as "hello world". Oddly, not all menu items are stuck, and it seems to only happen when the admin bar is being displayed on the front end (I don't see any "hello world" items on the back end). Any ideas?

Comment: can you please take a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: according to the documentation `If there are functions hooked to this filter, they will always run. This could lead to a performance problem`, is there any other function `test` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove the filter with `remove_filter`, here is the code:

```
// remove the filter 
remove_filter( 'gettext', 'test', 20, 3 );
```

Let me know if it goes ok, please.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this didn't work. I also tried `remove_all_filters("gettext")`, but nothing changed.

Comment: This turned out to be a plugin issue. I'm using TranslatePress and apparently when I created that filter, it resulted in database entries being created in the `wp_trp_gettext_en_us`. I found my "hello world" entries in there, among others. I just deleted all the rows in that table. The default rows were automatically regenerated, so all is well again.

Comment: Glad you found a solution @David